# How to close a non blocking socket channel properly?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, nonblocking

I'm writing a server program using Java non-blocking SocketChannel. Sometimes I want to send a reply message and then close the channel, like the following code.

However, the close() method interrupts the write() method, I get a java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException and the message is not sent.

I can pop a thread and wait for 1-2 seconds before closing the channel, but I feel it's so wasteful to making another thread.

What is the proper way to close a SocketChannel while there are pending operations?

```
String msg = "Wrong password!";
channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(msg.getBytes()));
channel.close();
```

Comment: That doesn't sound right. You must be doing a write *after* you've closed the channel. I have miles of code like this and it doesn't do that.

Answer (score -1):

channel.[socket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#socket%28%29)().[setSoLinger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoLinger%28boolean,%20int%29)(true, MAX_SECONDS_FOR_OUTPUT_TO_DRAIN);

See info on the [linger option](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html#SO_LINGER).  As mentioned, it will cause close() to block for up to MAX_SECONDS_FOR_OUTPUT_TO_DRAIN seconds.

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me, maybe it just for blocking socket?

Comment: It will only do that in blocking mode, where it's basically unnecessary in the first place. He's in non-blocking mode.